# What qualifications do the traders have that quants don't?

Tags: trading, quants

What qualifications do the traders have that quants don't?

I know that they are not expected to know as much math, but that can't be it, can it?

(I'm not in finance, nor am I really planning to go there. I'm just curious, so don't get too technical please)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The right amount of confidence and courage to take risks with other people's money without shading into overconfidence and bad judgement. Especially coping with the emotional pressure of losses without losing your head and doing the wrong thing. It also helps to do mental arithmetic quickly and accurately and have a good short term memory for figures, all in noisy, chaotic environment. (Notice that not much of this can be learned in a classroom...)

Comment: So a quant + the right amount of alcohol can be a trader?